# Perfect squares and divisor

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, square-numbers

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $d$ be a positive divisor of $2n^2$. Prove that $n^2+d$ is not a perfect square.

My working:
$d \mid 2n^2$
Let $d \cdot k=2n^2 \implies d=\dfrac {2n^2}k$
Therefore, $n^2+d=n^2\dfrac {k+2}k$
How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $d$ is a divisor of $2n^2$ we'll have:

$$\frac{2n^2}{d}=t\in \Bbb{Z}$$

So our expression becomes:

$$n^2+\frac{2n^2}{t}$$
$$n^2(1+\frac 2t)$$

This means that $1+\frac 2t$ have to be a square and this is banally never verified

:)

Comment: 1+2/t can be either 2 or 3, therefore, this necessarily means that 2n^2 or 3n^2 can never be a perfect square, right?

Comment: @LenaDas exactly

Comment: I think you should prove that $\left( 1 + \dfrac{2}{t} \right)$ is not a square of **a rational number**, although easy to do so.